# jquery uniform strange thing occurs when restoring (when rolling back / turning off unifrom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uniform

Uniform is a jQuery plugin for styling up the forms. I use it on my project and there I have a case where I need to turn off this plugin and turn on later.

You turn on plugin in a following way (one of the ways): `$("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();`

If you want to turn off a plugin (bring back old styles) you do: `$.uniform.restore();`

It works fine, but not on `button`, `submit`, or `reset`. When restoring a value of these inputs comes out and finds a place at the left side of original button.

Here is a jsFiddle link for you to see a demo: [jsFiddle uniform.js problem](http://jsfiddle.net/PDWRe/)

I tried to solve this but without luck. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a *very* crude fix for this:

```
$.uniform._restore = $.uniform.restore;
$.uniform.restore  = function(elem) {
  if (elem === undefined) {
     elem = $($.uniform.elements);
  }
  $(elem).each(function() {
     if ($(this).is("button, :submit, :reset, input[type='button']")) {
       this[0].parentNode.firstChild.nodeValue = '';
     }
  });
  $.uniform._restore(elem);
};
```

As shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PDWRe/1/), it works. But I'd rather fix this in the uniform source code (that's why it's hosted on github, afterall). )

Comment: great! you've done good job. thank you! this page will certainly be useful for a lot of people.